# Stripe monthly and yearly plans

Tags: payment, stripe-payments

Is it possible to create a plan that costs 30$ per month and one that costs 250$ per year, or do I have to create two different plans, one monthly and one annually and set different intervals and prices?

Comment: You may get a better answer if you simply send an email to Stripe, as the question doesn't involve any specific programming language task.